# React native chat : listView resize on keyboard

Tags: listview, react-native, keyboard, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I'm getting crazy with a React Native chat app.
I need the typical app structure: a listView (I also tried with FlatList or even ScrollView) and a textInput on the bottom.
When I focus on the input the listView get covered by the keyboard and I can't see what I'm typing.

I tried many approach but they all didn't work as I expected:
I used KeyboardAvoidingView and also tried with KeyboardAwareScrollView and KeyboardSpacer but I get a bug every time: when I focus on the input the list get cut during the animation and when I click outside of the input I have a white space on the bottom (which get fixed when I lightly scroll the list). 
Maybe I'm using a bad structure:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <Header />
  <ListView style={{ flex: 1 }} ...... />
  <InputContainer />

  <!-- here I tried to put -->
  <KeyboardSpacer>
</View>
```

or put Header, ListView and InputContainer inside KeyBoardAvoidingView with behavior="padding" or other settings. I basically tried everything.

I'm trying to avoid gifted-chat because I have to customize it and it's badly documented. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the height of the container in real time using the Keyboard.addListener method.

```
<Animated.View style={Platform.OS === 'android' ? {flex: 1} : {
   height: this.visibleHeight.interpolate({
   inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [
        height - (Define.system.ios.x ? 88 : 64), keyboardShow
          ? height - keyboardHeight - (Define.system.ios.x ? 88 : 64)
          : height - (Define.system.ios.x ? 112 : 64) - 240]
    })
  }
  } >

     <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ListView  ...... />
     </View
    <InputContainer />
</Animated.View>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. first take the container from the native base
2. take content from native base with [ scroll enabled = true ]
3. in content just put 2 views with flex 1 or flex 2
4. in 1 view put content inside the view
5. last there is some property of content just add them

   showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
   enableOnAndroid
   automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
   keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
   extraHeight={250}
6. finish

here is the design structure

```
<Container>

<Content>

<View>
<Contnet>
</Content>
</View>

<View>
view 2
</View>
```